# Azure Batch BlobNotFound error in pool start task

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I'm attempting to create a Batch pool of workers with a 'Start task' that that uses the Start task's 'Resource files' to download an application tar from blob storage and install it. I've placed the tar file in the blob storage account associated with the batch pool. Using the URL provided for the tar in the blob properties I've filled in the 'Blob Source' and added a valid 'File Path' and file mode '777'.

When I attempt to run a job against the pool I get the error:

> Failure info
>
> Category  UserError
>
> Code  BlobNotFound
>
> Message  One of the specified Azure Blob(s) is not found
>
> Details  BlobSource: ...

I've tried using two different blob storage accounts under the same subscription and different output paths to the same effect. Are there IAM rules or something else that needs configured for this feature to work?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `BlobSource` error and redact sensitive parts?

Comment: I've added an image of the error I'm seeing.

Comment: Batch will disambiguate between Not Found (404) and Authorization errors. Are you positive that the URL is correct? As an aside, you don't appear to have a SAS on the blob, so the blob itself must be public (which isn't recommended).

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. There was no indication in MS documentation or configuration instructions that I needed to do anything with SAS. I'm looking into it now but that is a huge thing for them to leave out. I figured a pool worker could access it's own blob storage.

Comment: Actually how could you configure a SAS for Batch workers? You need to specify IPs or IP ranges but the Batch pool is dynamically allocated.

Comment: You don't need to specify IP ranges for SAS (that's an optional parameter). The important thing is to specify a long enough end time (`se`) for the lifetime of your pool (through any autoscale or resizing). Optionally you can specify your own policy if you feel like you need to revoke it in the future.

Comment: Thanks @fpark, Setting up SAS was the answer!